# Webdriver - Unable to locate element (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new in Selenium and WebDriver.
I have this HTML:

```html
<input id="undefined-undefined-Jobsubject-5546" type="text" value="" data-test="testing-job-subject" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: medium none; outline: medium none; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: initial; font: inherit; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: 14px;"/>
```

and I have this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-test='testing-job-subject']"));
```

but the error is:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@data-test='testing-job-subject']

I tried also this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'undefined-undefined-Jobsubject')]"));
```

because the number in id is generated, so I can't take the By.id(....), but the same error.
And yes,I have in the code the timeouts,so the element is on the page.

Where is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There may be following reasons :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[data-test='testing-job-subject']")));
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[data-test='testing-job-subject']")));

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Comment: I tried the first reason, but still nothing, just another error:
"org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: input[data-test='testing-job-subject'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)"

And there is no frame or iframe :/

Comment: So how to be ensure you that there is no frame or iframe??

Comment: @Mephy Are you sure you have provided here right HTML code for the link element?? and also make sure this element is manually visible on the page..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[data-test='testing-job-subject']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("id*='Jobsubject'"));
```