# How can I access a button to click it with following code in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

There are many buttons sharing the same class.
May have to go with clicking the link /account/logout'.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
input class="btnRed text-uppercase fo_white" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='/account/logout';" type="button"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say because you didn't provide enough info, but you could probably make it work by using value attribute. Something like this if you are using java.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='Logout']")).click();
```

Not pretty solution, but give it a try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btnRed.text-uppercase.fo_white")).click();
```

Comment: it dint work.it flagged an error again: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: button[value='Logout']

Comment: Edited my code, try now and paste exception if you get one.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: [value='Logout']

Comment: OK, I added nasty solution in my post, try it and see if you are getting exception again.

Comment: i had tried that earlier as well. but it gave me a javascript error: JavaScript error: line 1: TypeError: chatWindow is null

Comment: What, javascript error? Ok, you are doing something wrong, can't help you. You are not showing us your code and you are getting errors which are inconsistent with my tips so who knows what is wrong here.

Comment: Hope this part of code helps. The site is not a public URL .
HTML code: 
<div class="row text-xs-center p-t-1"> HTML code : <input class="btnRed text-uppercase fo_white" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='/account/logout';" type="button"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML DOM this command will work for you:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Logout']")).click();`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Unable to locate element: //input[@value='Logout']

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the HTML DOM? If the url is public share the URL.

Comment: Not a public URL.<div class="row text-xs-center p-t-1">
             HTML code :   
                <input class="btnRed text-uppercase fo_white" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='/account/logout';" type="button">
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML, this should work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Logout'][@type='button']")).click();
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: dint work. Unable to locate element: //input[@value='Logout'][@type='button']

Comment: Then check for any frame change or page change. If there is any of the case then you have to first switch it to that particular frame/page.
Then only this xpath will work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your element visible/enabled? In order to select an element, it must be present in your DOM. If the element is activated through an event, it cannot be selected until the event occurs.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373814/webdriver-unable-to-locate-element-java). [This other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536954/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-nosuchelementexception-in-selenium) post also have good ideas.