# How to select a value from dropdown with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

This is the source code :

```
 <select name="backgroundcolor" onchange="backgroundColor();">
    <option value="200">Red</option>
    ....      
 </select>
```

I tried below code in order to select the "Red" option but it didn't work.

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("backgroundcolor")));
dropDown.selectByValue("200");
```

I'm getting `NoSuchElementException` Exception

> Unable to locate element //*[name='backgroundcolor']

Comment: Are you using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io)?

Comment: No , it's a FirefoxDriver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver - Unable to locate element (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373814/webdriver-unable-to-locate-element-java)

Comment: @gingerdd, If your issue has been resolved then post as an answer which you tried so far

Comment: @Tuks ok , done

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("backgroundcolor")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Red");
```

perhaps the By.name is the problem, i am used to using something like :

```
By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need to convert the below code to the language you are using

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select as WebDriverSelect
element = WebDriverSelect(driver.find_element_by_name('backgroundcolor'))
element.select_by_value('200')
```

Answer (score 0):

You note that it's possibly a timing issue. If so, you'll need to wait until the element appears on the page. Try this:

```
By locator = By.name("backgroundcolor");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(locator));
dropDown.selectByValue("200");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got " Unable to locate element *[name='backgroundcolor'] " error.I solved that problem when firstly I try to reach the iframe which contain that dropdown.It's a timing issue by the way.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(theindexofframe));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("backgroundcolor")));
```

You should wait for the iframe to be loaded after that you should wait for the "backgroundcolor" element to be loaded also.After that you can select the value from dropdown like this:

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("backgroundcolor")));
dropDown.selectByValue("200");
```